# GCP - Load data from BQ through a component

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

In Vertex-AI WorkBench, I am trying to create a component for a function that reads data from BigQuery and returns a pandas DataFrame. When I execute the function on its own, it works fine, however when I add the decorator there is an error and I don't understand why.

```
@component(base_image="python:3.9", output_component_file="load-data-from-bq-component.yaml")
def load_data_from_bq(bq_uri: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    '''
    Loads data from BigQuery table (BQ) to a dataframe
            Parameters:
                    bq_uri (str): bq table uri. i.e: example_project.example_dataset.example_table
            Returns:
                    pandas.DataFrame: a dataframe with the data from GCP loaded
    '''
    import pandas as pd
    
    if not bq_uri.startswith('bq://'):
        raise Exception("uri is not a BQ uri. It should be bq://project_id.dataset.table")
    logging.info("reading bq data: {}".format(bq_uri))
    project,dataset,table =  bq_uri.split(".")
    bqclient = bigquery.Client(project=project[5:])
    bqstorageclient = bigquery_storage.BigQueryReadClient()
    query_string = """
    SELECT * from {ds}.{tbl}
    """.format(ds=dataset, tbl=table)
    return (
        bqclient.query(query_string)
        .result()
        .to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorageclient)
    )
```

That is the code, just a basic function to read data. This is the error when I hit enter in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 2
      1 @component(base_image="python:3.9", output_component_file="load-data-from-bq-component.yaml")
----> 2 def load_data_from_bq(self: Optional[Any], bq_uri: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
      3     '''
      4     Loads data from BigQuery table (BQ) to a dataframe
      5             Parameters:
   (...)
      8                     pandas.DataFrame: a dataframe with the data from GCP loaded
      9     '''
     10     import pandas as pd

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kfp/v2/components/component_decorator.py:110, in component(func, base_image, target_image, packages_to_install, pip_index_urls, output_component_file, install_kfp_package, kfp_package_path)
     99 if func is None:
    100     return functools.partial(
    101         component,
    102         base_image=base_image,
   (...)
    107         install_kfp_package=install_kfp_package,
    108         kfp_package_path=kfp_package_path)
--> 110 return component_factory.create_component_from_func(
    111     func,
    112     base_image=base_image,
    113     target_image=target_image,
    114     packages_to_install=packages_to_install,
    115     pip_index_urls=pip_index_urls,
    116     output_component_file=output_component_file,
    117     install_kfp_package=install_kfp_package,
    118     kfp_package_path=kfp_package_path)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kfp/v2/components/component_factory.py:434, in create_component_from_func(func, base_image, target_image, packages_to_install, pip_index_urls, output_component_file, install_kfp_package, kfp_package_path)
    430 else:
    431     command, args = _get_command_and_args_for_lightweight_component(
    432         func=func)
--> 434 component_spec = extract_component_interface(func)
    435 component_spec.implementation = structures.ContainerImplementation(
    436     container=structures.ContainerSpec(
    437         image=component_image,
    438         command=packages_to_install_command + command,
    439         args=args,
    440     ))
    442 module_path = pathlib.Path(inspect.getsourcefile(func))

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kfp/v2/components/component_factory.py:310, in extract_component_interface(func)
    307 # Fixes exotic, but possible collision:
    308 #   `def func(output_path: OutputPath()) -> str: ...`
    309 output_names.add(output_name)
--> 310 type_struct = _annotation_to_type_struct(signature.return_annotation)
    311 output_spec = structures.OutputSpec(
    312     name=output_name,
    313     type=type_struct,
    314 )
    315 output_spec._passing_style = None

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kfp/v2/components/component_factory.py:131, in _annotation_to_type_struct(annotation)
    129     return None
    130 if hasattr(annotation, 'to_dict'):
--> 131     annotation = annotation.to_dict()
    132 if isinstance(annotation, dict):
    133     return annotation

TypeError: DataFrame.to_dict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

As mentioned before, the function works fine without the decorator, but I need to create a component to read data as part of a pipeline. How could I build it?